# Why did people in the USSR participate in elections?

Tags: soviet-union, election

It is well known that the elections in the USSR had only one candidate on the list, giving no real choice to the voter.

While it was possible to vote against a candidate, there was no realistic chance that the voter would be in the majority so that the candidate to fail.
Even more, there were much more effective means in acting against a politician: appealing to the local party office, then to a higher one, then possibly to the press, then to the authoritative people, and finally maybe to the prosecutor's office if any supposed crime is suspected (and just some above-average lifestile or improper behavior could be quite a sufficient reason for investigation or exclusion from the party). Voting against would be totally pointless.

That said, there was no punishment for non-participating (unlike North Korea by the way where voting is mandatory). Yet a lot of people participated in the elections. Moreover, the elections turnout in the USSR was much higher than the turnout in modern Russia where you can vote many ways for various politicians.

What was the reason for such high turnout? Some people claim it was because one could buy deficit foods at the voting points, but this does not seem a completely satisfactory explanation to me especially given that the practice of offering food at the voting posts was changing with time and reached the height in late USSR.

Comment: It's a very complex question, because the USSR's history spanned some seven decades, and over this period the situation changed a lot. Not that it ever approached true democracy; I mean the mood of the people and the extent to which people felt themselves free to forgo voting, taking part in demonstrations, attending meetings etc.

Comment: If a candidate did not manage to get at least 50% of the voters (including absent) he/she could not get elected.

Comment: Indeed. @SVilcans

Comment: I use the example of Soviet elections with only one candidate to illustrate the absurdity of the sentiment "I don't want to waste my vote." In those elections, voting against a candidate was pretty much wasting your vote. So when the guy comes home and his family asks "why'd you vote for him? You hate everything this guy stands for, and his personality too!" his response "I didn't want to waste my vote" sounds silly. That's how it sounds with 3 candidates, too. It's too bad the USA's first-past-the-post system led to two parties. People wouldn't say such things in parliamentary elections.

Answer (score 23):

From a comment by Sassa NF:

> In real life I asked my parents why they would still go and vote - I asked this after USSR collapsed. The answer was exactly what I said - "are you mad? It would instantly be known and there would be consequences"

I became curious and asked my mother. She was born in early 1950s, so her reply covers the years 1969 to 1986. (In 1986 the Perestroika began and the Soviet regime started loosening up).

She said she first attended elections, out of curiosity, in 1969, when she had become able to vote. She hardly attended any elections afterwards, up to 1989. There were no repercussions. She was a usual Soviet person, with a university degree (an economist).

Her brother was a Communist Party member, and served in a district committee apparatus actually (a kind of sub-Mayor's Office apparatus responsible for governing a district in Yekaterinburg, then Sverdlovsk). Furthermore, it was part of his duties to ensure the presence of "propaganda materials" of various sorts on the streets, as far as I remember.

The only reprimands she got were reprimands by her mother, my grandma, who reproached her mildly for being so negligent while her brother was sitting through the day in a voting station (he was on an election commission). He never suffered due to his sister's absenteeism.

My father never voted either. He woke up early on the day of voting and went to the voting station to buy some of the deficit goods before they've been sold out. That was quite an incentive. A Western person would find it hard to imagine what an incentive it was in a deficit economy. After buying the goods, he made an about-turn and went home, having done sweet FA in terms of actual voting.

He told me that hypothetically one could be reprimanded at work for not voting, and he suspects that one could fail to get some of the better amenities available to those who fawned to the system. That is, you could fail to obtain a tourist tour to a country in Eastern Europe. But he did not consider that a serious thing. He was not a Party member, and belevied the Black Sea coast to be a-okay for a family trip, if in exchange you could shirk at least partly from participating in the circus.

> What was the reason for such high turnout?

I tried to google for some texts written by professional historians on this topic. A quick googling brought up one small article, the author  of which (Alexander Fokin) mentions the importance of propaganda and the factor of people being cautious not to fall out of line, not to attract attention by their absenteeism. But was that hard enough incentive in the post-Stalin years? I also found a dissertation by a Podosinnikov Andrei, covering the period from 1950-1970. It states that the elections were widely propagandized and turned into a kind of holiday for the majority of the population. In that holiday atmosphere, it was just keeping with a tradition to go and "vote", even though the majority of the people understood the phoniness of the process.

I am sure that in the Stalin era my parents would have attended the elections: the fear was strong while Stalin was alive. But I have no reason to doubt their accounts of the 1970s-80s period. One could suggest that there was a wide-ranging manipulation of statistics by low-level commissions. My perfunctory googling brought up no works on that count. If I found some in the future, I'd expand my answer. Until then, it'll remain basically a couple of retold first-hand accounts.

---

References:

- [Александр Фокин: Выборы в СССР в 1960-1970-е гг.: симуляция или элемент демократии?](http://www.perspectivia.net/publikationen/shdp/fokin_elections)
- [Подосинников Андрей Юрьевич. ИСТОРИЧЕСКИЙ ОПЫТ ПРОВЕДЕНИЯ ВЫБОРОВ В ОРГАНЫ НАРОДНОГО ПРЕДСТАВИТЕЛЬСТВА НА ТЕРРИТОРИИ КУРСКОЙ ОБЛАСТИ В 1950-1970-е гг.](http://kursksu.ru/documents/diss_list/podosinnikov1.pdf)

Comment: It seems to me that either your relatives that you mention in this anecdote were highly atypical in their aversion to voting, or the official numbers were a lie. I'm kind of curious which it is.

Comment: @T.E.D. - It could be a bit of both. Such phenomenon as "pripiski" (приписки) was widespread in the Soviet economy: low-level distortion of statistics which amalgamated into large-scale distortion as statistics were passed higher. Maybe there was something of this kind during voting. I'm also curious.

Comment: This is also exactly the case with my parents - they can't recall a single time they participated in elections back in the day and they both were born after Stalin's death - luckily. But my grandfather, who was a member of the Soviet communist party, did vote periodically. My mother has told me no one from her family ever went to the polls, she recalls that party members from other families did vote actually. And the rest was probably just made-up stats.

Answer (score 17):

When you are talking about participation and the numbers of votes for the candidate, you should take into account that these numbers were mostly fake. Nobody really counted. Another thing which is difficult to understand for  Westerners is the permanent feeling of fear. People knew that there was a record,
who voted and who did not.
They also believed that it can be tracked how they voted.

And this really happened. You come to the polling place, you show your ID (internal passport), they will give you the paper, and make a notice that you voted.

Closer to the evening they would go search for people who did not vote, knock to their doors, and ask to vote. Nobody wanted trouble (with very few exceptions).

Anyway, people wanted their friends, neighbors and colleagues see them near the voting boots, not speaking of those plain cloth people who were always hanging around.

(This answer is a participant account).

Comment: One could just do some things under good pretext for not voting. For instance, go to dacha. I think nobody would be prosecuted for going to countryside in a sunny day instead of voting.

Comment: Yes.If you go to a dacha, you are supposed to vote there. Prosecuted? No, probably not. But the communist party committee of your employer may be informed. They also will not prosecute you. But you may have difficulties with promotion, with travel abroad etc. No one will explain you why.

Comment: Someone asked: "any examples of consequences of no voting". The problem is that you never know. You just face the consequences but you never know "of what". You can look for a job be always rejected, and no one will ever explain you why.

Comment: @Anixx no, you wouldn't dare go to dacha. Suppose, your boss asks you next Monday why you were so irresponsible as to ignore the voting. They'd steer the conversation towards whether you are having doubts in the communist ideology, not towards the wellbeing of your potatoes. In addition to that, the boss would also get a problem that in his organisation unit the anti-soviet sentiments are striving. Overall, take it the voting results are certainly not the indicator of political activity.

Comment: @Sassa NF this is totally unrealistic scenario. For a boss asking about not voting? Totally unrealistic. Note that if any monitoring of elections happened it would be secret.

Comment: @Anixx are you saying this from a Westerner's perspective or from Soviet perspective? Far smaller things got discussed with the boss (I am simplifying the title; it'd be discussed with part-org or prof-org, to be precise).

Comment: @Sassa NF far smaller, that is like what? Definitely smaller things could be discussed but do u have any examples of people being reprimanded for not voting (unles the voting happened in presence of superiors like in army where they could directly see u avoiding voting)?

Comment: @Anixx I don't have examples with written references. I don't follow your conclusion how discussion of smaller things like not turning up at the demonstration means bigger things don't get discussed. I deem it is rather the other way around - the people had the sense it is better not to try. "Be like others, don't stick out" is the motto. "Are you the cleverest one?" (rather crudely translated, yes) is a day-to-day reprimand. But please, consider the phrase commonly attributed to J.Stalin - "it doesn't matter how they vote, what matters is how it is counted"

Comment: @Sassa NF making you to participate in the demonstration is a direct duty of the trade union section of your enterprise. So they demand you to participate or they would reduce any trade union bonuses you otherwise would have. This is not connected to elections at all.

Comment: @Anixx It is your opinion, not real life. In real life I asked my parents why they would still go and vote - I asked this after USSR collapsed. The answer was exactly what I said - "are you mad? It would instantly be known and there would be consequences". But reading your comments to the others, and your own answer, I have to ask myself whether you have an agenda of posing USSR as a democratic country, rather than genuinely looking for answers.

Comment: "It would instantly be known" - to whom? Electoral comission? Certainly. KGB? Possibly... and what exactly consequences? Open reprimation on the work for not participating is excluded. Or do u have any example?

Comment: It was not the KGB which controlled every aspect of our life. It was the Communist party.

Comment: @Anixx well, you've just excluded the consequence that is most likely, I have no other answers for you. Do you expect the turnout to be high (genuine or forced)? Then you need to accept it will be very hard to find real life evidence of the consequences. Do you expect the non-participation to be very high? (So the consequences should be more readily available) Then you need to accept the attendance figures were faked. My explanation has been repeated many times, so I won't perpetuate this explanation loop.

Answer (score 13):

Even in USA your **participation** in elections is recorded: as you come to the booth, your name is marked in the logs. It was most certainly recorded in USSR, and, because of the "*propiska*" (the mandatory registration of your address with the local government), the officials knew exactly where to find those who showed their disloyalty to the government by refusing to participate vote. I've heard first-hand accounts from lower-level CPSU officials who were dispatched to those addresses at the end of the election day to find out if those who missed the vote had an acceptable excuse (such as illness) and remind them of their civic duties if they didn't.

Those who served in the Army had no choice at all. Some divisions had "voting competitions": the units competed to see who would vote faster. The soldiers lined up under their officers' supervision and when the command was given to vote at the start of election time, the lines would **run** through the booths, registering their votes **exactly as ordered** as quickly as possible. The unit that was the slowest was reprimanded for lack of discipline.

In short, participation in the elections, as well as the choices provided, weren't a matter of the citizen's free will in the USSR. It was a "*balagan*", a show. I'm not quite sure which purpose it served. Was it make-believe to show its citizens that their decisions mattered? Was it make-believe to show foreigners that USSR was a democracy? Was it jading its citizens against the idea of democracy? ("You think they vote in USA? Yeah, right, they vote for show just like you do here.") Was it only to detect insufficiently loyal citizens? Was it some combination of the reasons above?

Comment: According to this paper http://www.perspectivia.net/publikationen/shdp/fokin_elections , there were cases where candidates failed elections in the USSR. For instance, in 1969 105 candidates failed to get the majority and being elected.

Answer (score 6):

Just read the law.

The [Положение о выборах в Верховный Совет СССР (1945)](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0:Sbornik_zakonov_1938-1956.djvu/170) that is *The statue of elections to the Supreme Council of the USSR (1945)*  states:

> **Статья 106.** Если поданное количество голосов по округу составляет
>   меньше половины числа избирателей, имеющих право голосова­ния по этому
>   округу, Окружная избирательная комиссия по выборам в Совет Союза или
>   по выборам в Совет  Национальностей отмечает об этом о протоколе и
>   сообщает Немедленно в Центральную избирательную комиссию и в
>   Избирательную комиссию по выборам в Совет Национальностей Cоюзной,
>   автономной рес­публики, автономной области или националь­ного округа.
>   В этом случае Центральная из­бирательная комиссия назначает новые
>   выбо­ры не позднее, чем в двухнедельный срок после первых выборов.

slightly edited google translation:

> **Article 106.** If the specified number of votes in the electoral district is
>   less than half the number of voters eligible to vote in this district, 
>   the district election commission for elections to the Council of the
>   Union and for elections to the Council of Nationalities notes the fact in
>   the protocol and reports immediately to the Central Election
>   Commission and Electoral Commission for elections to the Council of
>   Nationalities of the union republic, the autonomous republic, the autonomous region or  the national area. In this case, the Central Election Commission shall
>   appoint new elections no later than two weeks after the first
>   election.

in other words, if the turnout was low they would have to repeat it all over again within two weeks.

That alone is a good reason to encourage participants.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, a dozen answers, but nobody mentioned this. According to [one Western paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/152354), there was a canvassing protocol in place:

> During the voter registration process, the work of the precinct election commissions seeking to compile exhaustive lists of residents is assisted by the internal passport regime under the control of the police and housing authorities and by the persistent door-to-door visits of agitators. Each agitator contacts twenty or so citizens to extract a personal commitment to vote; and on election day, the agitator, who is evaluated on the turnout voters (and normally is unable to go home until they have cast ballots), will seek out non-voters to bring them to the polls.

Up to 1984 or so , it was apparently followed. Only some 23,000 absentees were reported for that year's election (out of 184 million or so), i.e. a turnout of some 99.987% (same source).

Additionally, there was some massaging of the data, essentially by excluding non-voters from the registered pool as well (thus lowering the denominator, a bit):

> Friedgut notes that in 1970 3.32% of the adult population was not included in the official total for the electorate and estimates that 2.5% of this population were electoral avoiders.

And as it was typical of the USSR, they were gleefully breaking their own laws in some regards:

> Although Soviet law (e.g. Article 21 of the 1978 Law on Elections to the Supreme Soviet of the USSR) requires that the lists of electors be made public 20 days prior to election day, the number of registered voters is not revealed until after the
> election.

However, while this latter trick got them past 99% reported turnout, this is probably not the main mechanism that got 90%+ participation, i.e. the level of data faking (as estimated by Westerners) was not high, relative to actual turnout. (It was high relative actual *non-*turnout, i.e. actual non-turnout was some 500 times higher than officially reported, but this still was still relatively low, by Western standards.) Instead, canvassing was the the main method that some 90%+ of the people to vote (according to this paper).

Answer (score 1):

There have been many factors, indeed.

- People were **unaware** that other approaches exist. It is hard to believe for a Westerner, but the Kommunist propaganda worked very well: they really believed **this is the only way for voting**, and the [„rotting West“](http://www.bbc.com/news/blogs-trending-30105541) has even worse situation;
- The vast majority of people believed they could **change at least something on the local level.** E.g., electing a „better“ kommunist would help him to lobby the interest of a town on the „republican“ level;
- **„Donos“** ([Wikipedia, RUS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81)), a habit of filing complaints to KGB (or Trade Union, or a local Party Nucleus), as means for winning a competition, was widespread across the entire Soviet system. If you've seen *something* and didn't complain, there will be a complain on you (for non-complaining). So, if *Alice* didn't attend „elections“ and *Bob* has seen it, either there will be *Bob's* complain on *Alice* or *Charlie's* complain on both *Alice* (for non-attending) and *Bob* (for non-complaining);

  - This does not mean that KGB will necessarily come to take you to GULAG concentration camp the very next night at 4AM. But you may see some unexpected obstacles in your future activities: the smaller one is inability to get a free ticket to „pansionat“ (Holiday House) for your kids the next summer. There tickets were given by „Trade Unions“ to the most loyal „citizens“.
- Those who really understood the situation, also realized that those 99.9% votes were fake. **Regardless of whether or not you attend**, your „vote“ will be counted;
- Don't discount the importance of a chance of **buying deficit foods**, too. Despite of miserable „salaries“, the deficit was even stronger. Most of people had had *unused money*, and attending the „elections“ was a great opportunity to buy at least something. Also, I would oppose the point of *«the practice of offering food at the voting posts … reached the height in late USSR»*, to me it was the opposite: it started diminishing in late 1980's and almost lost by 1990 when there was nothing left to offer.

---

## Summary

The system has been built this way, there was literally no escape from it.

Comment: "electing a „better“ kommunist would help him to lobby the interest of a town on the „republican“ level;" - how they would do so without any alternatives on the voting list? They of course could replace that or this official but not via voting of course.

Comment: @Anixx, while this may not be the case in Russia itself, it was normal in occupied countries. For instance, in Ukraine of 1970's-80's: the 1st candidate was a local, Ukrainian national who arguably could lobby local interests on a „republican“ level. If he/she resigned (usually, due to „donos“), the 2nd one was sent from the Russia. **There are plenty of evidences** about this practice, for instance, in memories of Leo Kravchuk, ex-2nd secretary of the Kommunist Party of Ukrainian „Soviet Republic“, then the 1st President of Ukraine.

Comment: reporting misbehavior is not voting. You could not remove a candidate by voting. You could make a compliant or report the misbehavior so to remove him but could not remove by voting

Comment: @Anixx, filing a „donos“ on your non-voting slum neighbor is a different thing to an average person's reporting on an „elected“ Kommunist party member. The former was widespread, the latter probably exists only in fantasies of those who miss the Soviet Russia.

Comment: You gave yourself an example and then you say it was impossible? (btw, why u think I was talking about elected deputies?)

Comment: @Anixx, I never claimed that a „low-class“ Soviet could successfully file a „donos“ against a „high-class“ Kommunist party member. Instead, *the only way* how an average person could make any influence on the system were those, let me say, „elections“. This is what my answer is about. Sorry to say, but I see numerous times you are jumping into discussions without prior reading the questions/answers you're disputing. Please take your time and read my answer. I love comments of KGB-fans, but only when these comments are based on facts.

Comment: "I never claimed that a „low-class“ Soviet could successfully file a „donos“ against a „high-class“ Kommunist party member" - easily

Comment: Just so that you guys know, in english language "communist" is written with a 'c', unlike in German for instance.

Comment: @Bregalad, the difference between Russian regime and Marx' ideas is much bigger than between `Kommunism` and `Communism`.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who grew up in the USSR:

1. The voting percentage like 99.98% that was published in the newspapers was a fake.  The real numbers were 80-95% of those who voted.
2. There were people called agitators.  Their job was to go door-to-door asking citizens to vote.  They were not allowed to go home until they had achieved a certain percentage of turnout.  If there were not enough voters, they were not allowed to go home until midnight, when the election was over.  They appointed ordinary people as agitators, perhaps people you knew, and next time they might appoint you as an agitator.  It was easier to vote so as not to cause them problems.
3. Polling stations sold "deficit products" (goods that were usually hard to buy in your area).
4. Refusing to vote could attract unwanted attention from the authorities.  Although no one was imprisoned for it, no one knew what it would mean: maybe nothing, maybe they would not let you go on a business trip abroad or it would interfere with your career, etc.  It was easier to show up and throw the ballot in the ballot box.
5. Your workplace might have been informed who voted and who did not.  Again, your boss might have thought that because of the low turnout he would have some problems.  It is easier to vote than to risk worsening relations with them.

Answer (score -1):

Just as in the elections themselves, what actually went on in the USSR did not necessarily match what the rules and law said was going on.  People might be cautious that if you weren't seen voting, there would be consequences no matter what the law said.

Comment: Any examples for consequences for those who did not vote?

Comment: I wonder what the reason for downvoting this might be.

Answer (score -2):

I have found [this text](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CFQQFjANahUKEwjX76a6p7vIAhVBEXIKHa2UC04&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.econ.msu.ru%2Fcmt2%2Flib%2Fc%2F444%2Ffile%2FVoting_USSR.doc&usg=AFQjCNG4hc6t2lSVwMevJhjt3gL6jbbzhg) about Soviet elections turnout on the site of the Moscow State University. I do not know who is the author.

Some points:

- In election one could strike all the candidates and write in one's own. There was a place for doing so in the ballot. The voting list would not be considered invalid after that (unlike modern Russia). If the majority did so, the manually written in person would be considered elected.
- Sometimes there were instances when the inhabitants of a living block would agree not to go to elections for instance untill the state would not make a capital reconstruction of their house. This would be extraordinary incident reported to the highest levels and all the demands would be satisfied immediately. Because of this custom some elder people still say "lets not to go to elections because this and this not done" The author says this is because the people do not understand that Soviet rule is over and this would not work any more.

Comment: This is as easily opposed by my observations that the majority of older people do not understand why they should vote at all. If they would so easily see the point in voting with a single candidate on the ballot, why would they fail to see the point in voting with multiple candidates on the ballot? I don't think the reference you quote is a credible explanation.

Comment: (1) looks contradictory: what is "strike **all** the candidates" if there's only one? Also, there was **no place** in the ballot for writing your own candidate; all candidates must have been approved **before** the elections; I have seen a ballot with blank line only once, during „elections“ of a director of `kolhoz` (kind of 100 voters who lived in a single village), but definitely, that was not mainstream; (2) is an [anecdotal evidence](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Anecdotal_evidence) which hardly can prove anything.

Comment: @bytebuster  "if there's only one" - there could be elections into different bodies. The supreme council, the republican council, the city council, and also the judges were elected. So you could strike all of them.

Comment: @Anixx, any evidence of these multi-ballots have been prevalent? and again, any evidence of ballots with blank lines to fill? The original question is about the real soviet Russia, not about someone's fantasies about it.

Comment: The prescribed form of the 1937 ballot can be seen [here](http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/3415/leon-maksimow.15/0_31e6c_bab0a2e9_L.jpg) so it was not single entry by design. And had enough free space for adding an additional person.

Answer (score -6):

Soviet elections often had many candidates, indeed many parties. Of course ALL parties and candidates had to be approved by the appropriate bodies of the CPSU making them pretty much puppets of the CPSU (which was the whole point).

In addition to Alex's excellent summary of how the USSR worked (which many European countries are getting very close to, e.g. in the Netherlands every voter is recorded, which may or may not be linked to his actual votes cast (in case of electronic voting, they certainly have the option but whether it's actually done is not known to me), people might well vote for local people, especially in local and regional elections, hoping their village/town candidate might be able to do something for them in the higher levels of the party bureaucracy eventually.

Comment: "Soviet elections often had many candidates" - proof? Or cite at least one case where the number of candidates was greater than 1. "indeed many parties" - really? Which ones?

Comment: Any proof of the co-existence of different parties?